# Adding School Branch to the Moodle?

Tags: moodle

I am fairly new to Moodle. I want to know if I can use Moodle for multiple Branches of a School. Say School A has different Branches A', A" .. Can we use the same Moodle install for all of them ?
I read online in forums they said we might want to have different installs for different Branches ? But I think that will be overkill. Can I not directly add a Branch Name to the login Form and show a person only his Branch's data ?

Answer (score 2):

With the utmost respect, it sounds like you don't 'get' how Moodle is structured so I would suggest at the first instance that you seek assistance from a Moodle Partner, and many of them will be happy to do a free consultation, if that's any consolation.

Now to address your question.

The short answer is **yes**. Moodle can indeed support 'branches' as you put it.

There's three ways you can do this. The first two are relatively straight forward. The third is more technical.

**Method 1**. You can have a single Moodle site with each course being duplicated. So you would have courses like so:

- Maths Category

  - Maths 101 (New Jersey)
  - Maths 101 (New York)
- English Category

  - English 101 (New Jersey)
  - English 101 (New York)

This method is clean as it's simple to set up, but it's ridiculously high maintenance as you'll need to keep both courses up to date. Any updates will need to be applied to both courses. This is OK when you have two separate teachers that are precious about their content.

**Method 2**. You can have a single Moodle site, and one Moodle course per course taught at both schools, but have 2 groups in each course.

Read more about Moodle groups here: https://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Groups

This means you have one course, you make your changes once, all students will see the same thing, but the two classes will be dealt with individually in terms of learning records and collaboration.

**Method 3**. You can install multiple instances of Moodle on the same server. If you would like to consider this option, please contact a Moodle partner who will be able to walk you through the process - as I would suggest it's not something you can DIY.